# Logstash Elasticsearch plugin. Compare results from two sources

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, etl, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-plugin

I have two deployed Elasticsearch clusters. Data "surpassingly" should be the same in both clusters. My main aim is to compare **_source** field for each elasticsearch document from source and target ES clusters.

I created logstash config in which I define Elasticsearch input plugin, which run over each document in source cluster, next using elasticsearch filter look up the target Elasticsearch cluster and query from it document by _id which I took from source cluster, match results of the _source field for both documents.

Could you please helm to implement such a config.

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["source_cluster:9200"]
        ssl => true
        user => "user"
        password => "password"
        index => "my_index_pattern"
    }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => ["@version", "@timestamp"]
 }
     elasticsearch {
             hosts => ["target_custer:9200"]
             ssl => true
             user => "user"
             password => "password"
             query => ???????
             match _source field ???? 
         }
    }

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
}
```

Maybe print some results of comparison...

Comment: What about the documents that are in target but not in source? Your approach wouldn't catch them.

Comment: It should not be the case because target cluster has the data that migrated from source previously. The main aim is to check that everything presented in source is in target and the data is the same.

Comment: What do you think @Val is it possible to do so? Could you help me with such the plugin definition?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right approach as it would take a lot of time, i.e. one query to the target cluster for each document in the source cluster... imagine how long it'll take if you have millions or billions of documents?

Comment: Totally agree. It is quite expensive, I believe getting docs from source might work with scroll and slices (by chunks), however on target cluster indeed it might take lot of time valling API for each doc. But I think I am talking about less than 200gb data. I wanted just to test this option....

Comment: Anyway, @Val could you please help me with such config? Just for POC purposes?

Comment: How about using an [existing tool](https://github.com/olivere/esdiff)?

Comment: Looks good). Do you know if I can tell to the tool - retrieve only _source field?
And I don't see if it supports tls configuration for connection to ES. Are you sure it is mature tool?